# Python numpy where function behavior

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, substring, conditional-statements

Have a question regarding using numpy's where condition. I am able to use where condition with == operator but not able to use where condition with "is one string substring of another string ?"

CODE:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import datetime as dt
    import numpy as np

    data = {'name': ['Smith, Jason', 'Bush, Molly', 'Smith, Tina',    
        'Clinton,     Jake', 'Hamilton, Amy'],
        'age': [42, 52, 36, 24, 73],
        'preTestScore': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3],
        'postTestScore': [25, 94, 57, 62, 70]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['name', 'age', 'preTestScore',     
    'postTestScore'])
    print "BEFORE---- "
    print df
    print "AFTER----- "
    df["Smith Family"]=np.where("Smith" in df['name'],'Y','N' )
    print df
```

OUTPUT:

```
    BEFORE-----

                name  age  preTestScore  postTestScore
    0   Smith, Jason   42             4             25
    1    Bush, Molly   52            24             94
    2    Smith, Tina   36            31             57
    3  Clinton, Jake   24             2             62
    4  Hamilton, Amy   73             3             70


    AFTER----- 
                name  age  preTestScore  postTestScore Smith Family
    0   Smith, Jason   42             4             25            N
    1    Bush, Molly   52            24             94            N
    2    Smith, Tina   36            31             57            N
    3  Clinton, Jake   24             2             62            N
    4  Hamilton, Amy   73             3             70            N
```

Why numpy.where condition  does not work in the above case.
Had expected Smith Family to have values 
Y
N
Y
N
N

But did not get that output. Output as seen above is all N,N,N,N,N
Instead of using condition "Smith" in df['name'] (also tried str(df['name']).find("Smith") >-1 )    but that did not work either.

Any idea what is wrong or what could I have done differently?

Answer (score 3):

I think you need [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) for boolean mask:

```
print (df['name'].str.contains("Smith"))
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
Name: name, dtype: bool

df["Smith Family"]=np.where(df['name'].str.contains("Smith"),'Y','N' )
print (df)
                name  age  preTestScore  postTestScore Smith Family
0       Smith, Jason   42             4             25            Y
1        Bush, Molly   52            24             94            N
2        Smith, Tina   36            31             57            Y
3  Clinton,     Jake   24             2             62            N
4      Hamilton, Amy   73             3             70            N
```

Or [`str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html):

```
df["Smith Family"]=np.where(df['name'].str.startswith("Smith"),'Y','N' )
print (df)
                name  age  preTestScore  postTestScore Smith Family
0       Smith, Jason   42             4             25            Y
1        Bush, Molly   52            24             94            N
2        Smith, Tina   36            31             57            Y
3  Clinton,     Jake   24             2             62            N
4      Hamilton, Amy   73             3             70            N
```

If want use `in` working with scalars need `apply`:

*This solution is faster, but doesnt work if `NaN` in column `name`.*

```
df["Smith Family"]=np.where(df['name'].apply(lambda x: "Smith" in x),'Y','N' )
print (df)
                name  age  preTestScore  postTestScore Smith Family
0       Smith, Jason   42             4             25            Y
1        Bush, Molly   52            24             94            N
2        Smith, Tina   36            31             57            Y
3  Clinton,     Jake   24             2             62            N
4      Hamilton, Amy   73             3             70            N
```

Comment: Yes jezrael. Your answer does work and was very helpful.

Comment: Can you also let me know why the np.where() works with == but not with string find or substr in str function.

Comment: I think main reason is if use `find` or `substr` it works only with scalar, but in pandas are used arrays. So need pandas text function like `str.find` or `str.startswith` - see [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html). Nice day! And you can accept my solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of `np.where("Smith" in df['name'],'Y','N' )` depends on what `df['name']` produces - I assume some sort of numpy array.  The rest is `numpy`

```
In [733]: x=np.array(['one','two','three'])
In [734]: 'th' in x
Out[734]: False
In [744]: 'two' in np.array(['one','two','three'])
Out[744]: True
```

`in` is a whole string test, both for a list and an array of strings.  It's not a substring test.

`np.char` has a bunch of functions that apply string functions to elements of an array.  These are roughly the equivalent of `np.array([x.fn() for x in arr])`.

```
In [754]: x=np.array(['one','two','three'])
In [755]: np.char.startswith(x,'t')
Out[755]: array([False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
In [756]: np.where(np.char.startswith(x,'t'),'Y','N')
Out[756]: 
array(['N', 'Y', 'Y'], 
      dtype='<U1')
```

Or with `find`:

```
In [760]: np.char.find(x,'wo')
Out[760]: array([-1,  1, -1])
```

The `pandas` `.str` method appears to do something similar; applying string methods to elements of a data series.